# Does my wood stove pipe have to be chrome to be safe to use?

Tags: insulation, safety, fireplace, woodstove

I'm currently renting a house that has a wood stove, and figured that as it's used as a rental property, the stove would be safe to use. However a friend of mine today was telling me that if the chimney is not chrome plated both inside and out that it could be uninsulated and be unsafe to use. The stack outside is chrome plated, the inside looks to just be cast iron, as the attached picture shows.

[image]

Can anyone advise if he's right, or if I can safely start firing up the stove ASAP.

Comment: Cast Iron. Heh. Rolled sheet iron single wall pipe with stove blacking or high temp paint. Looks like it's inserted into a triple-wall insulated stack.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Ya I'll be the first to admit ignorance on the composition of metals.

Comment: No worries on that, taking care to have a safe installation and knowing proper firing and stove safety with periodic chimney cleaning are vastly more important than knowing the metal. Having grown up with cast iron stoves, it just tickled my fancy imagining the weight of a cast stove pipe...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your friend is absolutely wrong. Color doesn't make any difference, and the outside is not chrome, it is stainless steel insulated pipe. Insulated pipe is not required from the stove to the ceiling where it adapts to insulated pipe

Comment: Also don't forget, the pipe in the room being hot is not a bad thing.  It just allows more heat to be transferred into the room.

Comment: And if the stove pipe blacking starts to turn color, it shows that you need to back off on your fuel loading. Stick a stack gauge on it and monitor the temperature to keep from sooting, creosoting or overfiring and you'll have a long chimney life.